# Billing plan patch: HTTP 400 - Invalid Path provided

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to delete all `CREATED` business plans:

```java
for (Plan plan : created.getPlans()) {

    List<Patch> patchRequestList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, String> value = new HashMap<>();
    value.put("state", "DELETED");

    Patch patch = new Patch();
    patch.setPath("/v1/payments/billing-plans/" + plan.getId());
    patch.setValue(value);
    patch.setOp("replace");

    patchRequestList.add(patch);

    plan.update(apiContext, patchRequestList);
}
```

but all I'm getting is:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/P-8SX60559PJ5455037EICJEYY
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1889)
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/#plan_update) I think I'm doing it correct. However, I've tried

```java
patch.setPath("/v1/payments/billing-plans/" + plan.getId());
patch.setPath("/v1/payments/billing-plans");
patch.setPath("/payments/billing-plans);
```

etc. but none of these are working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I confused things a bit. The [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/#plan_update) says

```
{
  "path": "/",
  "value": {
    "state": "ACTIVE"
  },
  "op": "replace"
}
```

and they *really* mean that:

```java
Patch patch = new Patch();
patch.setPath("/");
patch.setValue(value);
patch.setOp("replace");
```

and of course it makes sense. Why would you set the path since

```
plan.update(apiContext, patchRequestList);
```

will do that for you already. I guess `patch.setPath()` is here to set an additional *relative* path.

Now you know.